# Git checkout: How to remove old commits of a particular folder while maintaining new ones for another folder

Tags: git

supposing that I am working on two folders in two separated branches.

I have in a folder A some commits: cA1, cA2, cA3, ....cAN and in the folder B cB1, cB2, cB3, ....cBN.

after a merge, I noticed that I have to go back to an old commit for the folder A: for example go back to cA2 without removing the new commits on the folder B.

How can I do it?

please help me!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Permanently reset subdirectory to specific past state](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10597089/permanently-reset-subdirectory-to-specific-past-state)