# Git Merge, Ignoring Changes to Certain Files (Ours vs Theirs)

Tags: git, branching-and-merging

### Setup

A company is doing some work for us, forked off of of `master`, and has been opening pull requests against a feature branch that is dedicated to this effort.  We don't (currently) have a transpiler, and when I asked the company to take out any ES6+ notations from front-end, they also changed notations on the backend. This was both unnecessary and, in many cases, harder to read.

### Problem

I want to merge the PR but then only merge certain file changes into my `develop` branch.  How do I either ignore changes to certain files or revert just those files, resulting in a commit that I can pull into my `develop` branch, preferably via another PR?

Any thoughts?

Comment: Merge it into a different branch spawned from develop, do a `git commit --amend` to fixup the merge commit and restore the files you want. That's one way. Can you augment the PR by adding your own commits on top of the branch they're trying to merge? If so then you could do similar work there, either by manually reverting certain files in a new commit or ammending their commits. You can always also just cherry-pick and ammend commits one by one, or just do the PR as normal and create another commit on top undoing those files.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Permanently reset subdirectory to specific past state](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10597089/permanently-reset-subdirectory-to-specific-past-state)

Comment: @RobinGreen, it's a similar solution, yes.  They are dealing with a particular sub directory, rather than a smattering of individual files, but the solution is similar.  Thanks.

Comment: Hey @astangelo, have you merged the pull request? I guess you used one of the answers, you should consider [marking it as accepted](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers), even if it's your own one. Btw, I renamed branches in my answer to better match your problem.

Comment: I would use a mergetool.

Comment: @Frax, thanks for the follow-up.  Yeah, I wasn't allowed to accept my own answer on Friday.  Thanks for the follow-up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I get nervous monkeying up-and-down the commit tree, so my preference is to always branch and merge.  The below is **far more than needs to be done**, but I like the reversion path, should anything go wrong. **So feel free offer suggestions.**

1. Make note of the feature branch's head's commit hash, for later use.
2. Create a "clean" branch off of the feature branch.
3. Merge the PR into the feature branch.
4. Checkout the files you want to revert, from the previous commit

   - `git checkout *commit* -- file/path/one.js file/path/two.js`
5. Commit your staged changes
6. Create PR back into your feature branch

The quicker method would be to:

1. Make note of the feature branch's head's commit hash, for later use.
2. Merge the PR into the feature branch.
3. Checkout the files you want to revert, from the previous commit

   - `git checkout *commit* -- file/path/one.js file/path/two.js`
4. Commit your staged changes

Both strategies create a new commit to re-write the files back as they were before the PR.

**Note:** Take a look at @Frax's answer for a clearer commandline variant.

Comment: You could use `--amend` in point 4. of the second version to squash the change into one commit, that seems to be a cleaner solution - you avoid keeping phantom back-and-forth changes in the history. Nothing bad in amending a fresh commit, just treat the temporary version as, well, temporary :)

Comment: @Frax, I'll give it a try.  I haven't worked with amending remote commits (as the PR will be merged remotely).  But I suppose it can't be too different.  Thanks.

Comment: If you indeed make the merge remotely, I'd actually advice against `--amend`, force pushing is bad. But, actually, that made me think about much simpler solution, I'll post it in a moment.

Answer (score 0):

It may not work in all cases, but seems like it should work in yours: **simply revert the changes before the merge**.

Given that your pull request is from branch `pull-request` to `develop`, that could be just:

```
git checkout pull-request
# check out files from develop, they will be immediately staged
git checkout develop -- file/to/revert other_file/to/revert
git commit -m 'Reverted files that should be reverted'
git push origin pull-request
```

This should add the pull request to no longer include the offending files, so you can simply merge it.

Comment: This is close but the changes I wanted were further back in the feature branch.  And I didn't have access to the fork being merged back in, so I couldn't overwrite any files, prior to merging the PR.  Thank you.